# iOS app validation errors

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ios10

Today I was trying to upload my app to the iOS app store, but was unsuccessful. I tried different techniques like through Application Loader, but nothing worked for me. Then I read at some blog to validate the app first before uploading. And while uploading I got this issue (see screenshot).

I am using Mac OS Sierra, and Xcode 8.2 beta

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Xcode 8.2 beta and the error tells you not to use beta. Use the GM version of Xcode 8.2 and macOS Sierra. It's that simple.